# Android Google Map V2 Rendering issue

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google Maps V2. I can view the map when I open my app but if I move the map around it doesnt seem to render the map. Even if I zoom in it seems to not change and all I get is a pixelated view of the map. Here is my code that I am using

```
public class MapList extends Activity {
    GoogleMap mapItem;
//@SuppressLint("NewApi")

      @SuppressLint("NewApi")
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.pharmview);
            //Reading the lat long from a database. 
            LatLng test = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(pointsVal[1]), Double.parseDouble(pointsVal[0]));

            mapItem = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            mapItem.clear();

            mapItem.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

            //mapItem.notify();
            Marker hamburg = mapItem.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(test)
                .title(separatedInside[0]));

            mapItem.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(test, 15));

            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            mapItem.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }
}
```

Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:prompt="@string/item_prompt" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="286dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

I have googled it but wasnt able to find any solutions. Please help as I need to be able to move the map.

EDIT - ADDED THE MANIFEST FILE.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="test.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />   


<permission
      android:name="test.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="test.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="test.myapp.medsready.MapList"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_API_KEY" />
</application>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you cross checked your api keys and permissions?

Comment: Yes I have checked everything. The Map initially displays but as soon as I move around it doesnt display anymore. Also using HTC One-x to test it just incase that matters. I have checked all permissions as well. There is no error displaying. The Map just does not seems to want to render on the App

Comment: please put manifest permission section too

Comment: Dont think it is the permission but I have added it above and yes I know I have multiple permission listed there. Will clean it up soon.

Comment: Not sure what happened but its working fine this morning. Thanks for your help.